# Alguem sabe pegar dados da celula do grid?

Tags: c#, webforms

Boa noite galera, eu tenho um grid de historico onde aparece o serviço prestado e tenho mais dois grid abaixo com os debitos pagos e debitos pendentes que eu queria pegar da clinha do grid de cima no qual citei primeiramente que seria o do cliente. Clicando na linha do cliente para aparecer os debitos nos grids debaixo aparece a seguinte mensagem  " metodo ou ação nao pode ser implementada " e o programa fecha. Alguem poderia me ajudar ?

```
 private void MontarListaDebitosCliente()
        {
            Int32 clienteid;
            string Mensagem;
            clienteid = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
            Mensagem = bll.MontarListaDebitosClientes(clienteid);
            //Se ocorrer erro exibi-lo
            if (Mensagem != "") MessageBox.Show(Mensagem, "Erro encontrado:");
            //exibe na dataGridView os dados carregados na Classe/STP
            dataGridView2.DataSource = bll.DTPendentes;
            //    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

            dataGridView2.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            dataGridView2.ClearSelection();
        }
```

Comment: Poderia colocar um pouco do código na sua pergunta?

Comment: Você está criando algum link em uma das colunas do grid?

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

ao usar

```
Cliente cliente = (Cliente)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
```

você consegue direto o objeto que foi selecionado. Daí, é só buscar os dados das outras grids por esse objeto.

Esperto ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

```
clienteid = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.toInt32();
```

talvez assim